# how to groupby and custom calculate in linq to Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table with these columns:

```
guid Id
string UserId
bool IsActice
datetime duedate
```

When a user activated, one record insert into above table and `isActive` column is true.

When he/she disable activation, another record insert into db and `isActive` column is false.

Now I want select and group by month & day (by `duedate` column) then show count of `isActive` users in a date

eg:

[image: eg]

How do I do that?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I should also ask, your text says "month and day" but your example shows year as well. Should 12/2/2015 be grouped with 12/2/2014 or are they separate groups?

Comment: arash jan kheili fullenglish gofti :) saadetar bego lotfan

Comment: @Abolfazl Rajabpour It means ,put some of your code here.You can't ask question like this,your qestion should have some code that you have already wrote then ask question base on that code(farsi.. harf nazan:))

Comment: @AbolfazlRajabpour - I appreciate you using ISO date format. +1

Comment: If a user was activated, then deactivated, then activated again all in the same day, do you want to include him twice in the count for that day? Or once? Please explain in more detail what do you mean by "activeUsers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to consider a query to compute activation delta (`= numberOfActivation - numberOfUnactivation`) per date.

```
var activityDeltaPerDate = table
     .GroupBy(x => x.duedate.Date) // group by date ignoring time
     .Select(group => new { // for each group, sum activation and unactivation
       Date = group.Key,
       Delta = group.Sum(x => x.IsActive ? 1 : -1)
     });
```

Number of activated user at a specific date is the sum of delta until this date.
So, you have to consider an enumeration giving all dates interesting you:

```
var firstDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
    .Select(x => firstDate.AddDays(x));
```

Now, you can compute the number of activated user at each date:

```
var activitedUsersPerDate = dates
    .Select(x => new {
      Date = x.Date,
      ActivatedUsers = activitedUsersAtDate.Where(y => y.Date <= x.Date).Sum(y => y.Delta)
    };
```

If you want number of activated users per Month, just change the `GroupBy` key selector to select the first day of the month: `x => new DateTime(x.duedate.Year, x.dueDate.Month, 1)` and change changes the `dates` collection by using `AddMonths` instead of `AddDays`.